# AngularJS - Unable to remove hover style after another style added on click

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm learning angular and trying to create a simple interface where the user is able to click on an element (out of possible 3) and some `css` applied. When user hovers over the elements another affect is applied. My current issues are:
1. I achieved the desired functionality, however I feel like this is "not the angular way", but rather looks like a hack.
2. Once the user hovers an element and selects it, I dont know how to disable the hover effect for that element.

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgg2eby6/), please advise.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 statTab" id="1" ng-click="toggleSelected($event)" ng-class="{'statNumberActive' : toggle1}">
          <span class="statNumber">0</span>
          <span class="statDescription">Views</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 statTab" id="2" ng-click="toggleSelected($event)" ng-class="{'statNumberActive' : toggle2}">
          <span class="statNumber">0</span>
          <span class="statDescription">Reads</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 statTab" id="3" ng-click="toggleSelected($event)" ng-class="{'statNumberActive' : toggle3}">
          <span class="statNumber">0</span>
          <span class="statDescription">Commens</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 var myApplication = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApplication.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggleSelected = function(item) {
    var id = item.currentTarget.id;
    switch (id) {
      case "1":
        $scope.toggle1 = true;
        $scope.toggle2 = false;
        $scope.toggle3 = false;
        break;
      case "2":
        $scope.toggle1 = false;
        $scope.toggle2 = true;
        $scope.toggle3 = false;
        break;
      case "3":
        $scope.toggle1 = false;
        $scope.toggle2 = false;
        $scope.toggle3 = true;
        break;
    }
  }
 }]);
```

CSS:

```
.statNumberActive {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.statNumber {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  letter-spacing: -.04em;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.statDescription {
  color: rgba(109, 109, 109, 0.3);
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all ease .3s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.statTab {
  height: 76px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: rgba(109, 109, 109, 0.3);
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.statTab span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.statTab:hover > span {
  color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.47);
}
```

Comment: it seems you entered a wrong fiddle. it is about an example on using filters inside a controller.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the link.

Comment: Not related to your question but still: try not to write "$scope.someproperty = value". Usually you should reference controller's property and reference this property in your view through controller's instance like "mycontroller.someproperty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle please check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgg2eby6/1/)

> .addHover:hover > span {
>     color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.47);
>   }

in ng-class i have updated this

> ```
>     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 statTab addHover" id="2" ng-click="toggleSelected($event)" ng-class="{'statNumberActive' : toggle2,'addHover':!toggle2}">
> ```

Now the selected item hover wont happen

Comment: It mostly does. But i believe my approach with the `switch` statement is not quite angular, is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: @undroid: not sure about your application needs but there is a better way to do this if we use ng-repeat to build the dom see this  link http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/3G7Kd/ , should provide you an idea